# sqlite3 query Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm relatively to SQLite3 so I want to make a query that makes a multi-word search, I've tried using Match Against to make a full text search, as it can be done in MySQL, but it didn't work since SQLite3 doesn't support this type of queries. so I would like to know how can this be done, and also if SQLite3 have some especial commands to make more complex queries. any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've looked for a while into SQLite documentation but no luck :(

```
SELECT product,category FROM products 
WHERE MATCH(product,category) AGAINST ('text')
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up `How to select sqlite`?

Comment: Are you asking specifically for a equivalent "match" function in SQLite or are you just asking how to accomplish your search goal?  Because a LIKE statement would do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for MATCH specific type searches:

http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3

However, if you need to simply get results:

http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like

Answer (score 1):

If I were to wager

```
SELECT product,category FROM products WHERE product='Deep Cycle' AND category LIKE '%Battery';
```

I got that from the first [two results](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+select) below.

Comment: Why `product='text'` and `category LIKE 'text'`? if text doesn't present it will give 0 results.

Comment: I was just trying to match the supplied arguments. Any suggestions for what else to put in?

Comment: You have to match specific text in both of these columns So you should use **OR**, Moreover searching specific text should be `LIKE '%text%'`. It will allow to look for text within specific column. The way your are doing is nothing but same. I mean `category LIKE 'text'` is nothing but `category = 'text'` and same goes for product.

Comment: Yeah, I knew `product` was a direct compare, but I'm not familiar with sqlite, so I kinda glazed over `like`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not only your product but category also. See my previous comment.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the user can use a sentence, but works, inspired on this. I used like as you said from an array of words that I've created from the sentence and then eliminated the duplicates with a boolean vector but still the full text search is always a better option